# Dynamic SQL not working for changing variable column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to write a stored procedure which can be used to update IDs of owner name, backup contact, other contacts etc in a table. These IDs are to fetched from some other table. Instead of writing different stored procedure for all these contact information, I want to write a single dynamic SQL in which I can pass the column name as a variable name.

My stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateUser
    (@recordid [NVARCHAR](50),
     @id [NVARCHAR](10),
     @user [NVARCHAR](50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @sql = N'UPDATE [dbo].[table1]
                 SET'+ QUOTENAME(@user) + ' = (SELECT [dbo].[table2].User
                                               FROM [dbo].[table2]
                                               WHERE [dbo].[table2].id = ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + ')
                WHERE record = ' + QUOTENAME(@recordid)

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
GO
```

After executing the query it runs without error but the user is not changed in table1.

What is missing in the procedure?

Comment: What does the query look like if you add `print @sql` before `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` ?

Comment: I can see the a space missing after SET in the update and all the variable values in [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't inject your parameters, parametrise them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateUser
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(   @recordid [nvarchar](50), --Are your IDs really an nvarchar?
    @id [nvarchar](10), --Are your IDs really an nvarchar?
    @user sysname --As this is an object, lets use the correct datatype
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @sql= N'UPDATE [dbo].[table1]' + @CRLF +
              N'SET ' + QUOTENAME(@user) + N' = (SELECT [table2].User' + @CRLF + --3 part naming for columns is deprecated, don't use it
              N'       FROM [dbo].[table2]' + @CRLF +
              N'       WHERE [table2].id= @id)' + @CRLF + --3 part naming for columns is deprecated, don't use it
              N'WHERE record = @recordid;';

   --PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id nvarchar(10), @recordid nvarchar(50)', @id, @recordid; --Assumes that IDs are an nvarchar again
END;
GO
```

Note I've left some comments in there for you to consume and review as well.

Comment: Glad to have helped, @richaverma . If this does answer the question, please consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful.

Comment: What is parametrizing the parameters ?

Comment: Not sure how else to describe that, @richaverma . I passed the parameters as parameters.

Comment: still don't understand how was In my question parameters are injected and how in the solution it is parametrized

Comment: @richaverma `'....id = ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + ...` is **injecting**.

Comment: On the other hand `'... id = @id ...'` and then passing `@id` as a **parameter** to `sp_executesql` isn't injecting, it's parametrising. These are, I'm afraid, the basics of using SQL. If you aren't familiar with SQL injection, then have a look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) page and [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).